# how solve exception UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in netbeans 8 running in windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

when running project in netbeans 8 the following error appear Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: src/cpabe/bsw/accessStructure/AccessTree : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0.

i read that i need to download jre 8 but after download and run it the same error appear.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because the jar was compiled in jdk 1.8, but you are running  it using a jdk 1.7.